# Why is there no rock-n-roll on Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, rock-music

Every time we see a recital given aboard any ship or star base, it's almost always a 'classical music' recital or performance, never a rock concert. The only exceptions to this musical bias are Riker's penchant for Jazz and Zefram Cochrane playing 'Magic Carpet Ride' during the 'First Contact' launch.

Comment: Don't forget Ooby Dooby on the juke box in FC too.

Comment: @Xantec = True that, good point. That Cochrane was a real party animal.

Comment: Licensing costs and negotiations? You can pull that off for a feature film but it is much harder for episodic television that is heading for syndication.

Comment: *Star Trek* is set in a future centuries ahead of ours.  If they are listening to genre music from our period it would be a genre that has stood the test of time.  Rock and roll was going strong when the original *Star Trek* series aired, but was still a teenager as a genre.  The series that followed stuck with jazz and classical music because those forms had proven staying power and had already ossified into a standard repertory.  Given the expected institutional patronage both forms will endure for centuries to come.  We're nowhere near that with rock and roll. Probably never will be.

Comment: Are you counting Abrams Trek? They did have Kirk playing Beastie Boys in each of those movies ('Sabotage' in the first, 'Body Movin' in the second)

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Way_to_Eden_(episode)

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rock_and_roll

Comment: Nice one, Richard. But that caption just takes the cake: "A punk listening to rock and roll on his boombox." Much wikipedian!

Comment: I'd swear there's an episode of TNG with some punk kid listening to death-metal real loud, I can't find it though.

Comment: @Mazura Are you sure it was TNG and death-metal? Because I remember that the more realistic son of the Doctor was a fan of Klingon-Gothic-Metal?

Comment: Roddenberry hated hippies.

Comment: There was an episode of TOS with hippies. IIRC there's rock song in that one.

Comment: @Mazura You're probably thinking of the episode [Suddenly Human](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Suddenly_Human_(episode)) when Jono is listening to Talarian "[Alba Ra](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Alba_Ra)".

Comment: By no means a canon answer but consider that: looking at it from the far future: rock, was really only popular **for a very short time**. Although hugely influential today, it was only a "passing phase" (say ... 30 yrs at most) versus "classical" ("violin") music, popular for 100s of years. One way to think of it: you can imagine NOT hearing "disco" in that future: after all disco was just a passing phase - right?  Really, on a long scale, rock is/was only just a short-term thing. Maybe that helps!

Comment: I think it's an outstanding observation that the musical "feel" of ST indeed does not (generally) include rock. perhaps the more "thoughtful" nature of the future gives this direction (much as, on the whole, we've outgrown "money" .. perhaps).

Comment: @luserdroog That would be The Way to Eden.  There's [this number](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=o5bB4ZRdPEI#t=1796) which is followed by the groovy Spock duet.

Comment: Realistically, you'd expect to hear both classical music (Bach, Beethoven, Beatles) and more modern genres. The trouble with the latter is that the writers would have to invent 23rd- and 24th-century musical genres.

Comment: @luserdroog: And after watching the episode in question, an eight year old me also decided to forever hate hippies.

Comment: TOS Episode "The Way to Eden" has a folk-rock song and an instrumental jam session...zheesh you kids don't know your future history

Comment: I would love to hear a TOS reference to Rock and Roll:  "I listen to all the Greats: The Beatles, The Rolling Stones, and Kryllin of Altair VI."

Comment: @Mazura: I think it was Voyager, the one where the Doctor had simulated a holo-family for himself; his holo-son was into Klingon heavy-metal, IIRC.

Comment: Maybe classical music is written down in sheet form whereas rock & roll and modern music is held on discs or in digital form that the future people don't know how to read.

Comment: @NigelEllis Random Starfleet personnel are able to interface with alien computers upon first contact and decipher data crystals and other storage media produced by other civilizations millennia ago. You don't think they can figure out how to drag a needle over a vinyl record? Similarly, magnetic tape recordings use a straightforward analog format that automatically induces the proper electrical signal when an electromagnetic transducer is dragged across it.

Comment: I'm also fairly certain their records from the 21st century aren't all based on scanned photos and books. But even if there were no digital records from the 21st century, they could still find printed specifications of the red book standard, AAC, MP3, etc., which would allow any decent programmer to figure out how to decode those formats.

Comment: Nobody remembers Cochrane slamming in a recording of Steppenwolf's "Magic Carpet Ride" during the launch of the Phoenix in First Contact? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYE3nm9voUk

Comment: I'm certain that in 2364, Pink Floyd's "Dark Side Of The Moon" will still be in the charts.

Comment: From the vantage point of the 24th century, the late 20th century could well be sort of "lumped together" as a common time period.  And in the Star Trek universe, that period features the Eugenics Wars and the lead-in to WW III.  Maybe pop music from that time invokes a time of darkness and hardship nobody wants to tap their toes to...

Comment: I recall a John Varley novel where the protagonist did a time dilation space trip to the future.  One of her many peeves of future Earth was never being able to hear the Beatles' music except played in a concert hall by a symphony orchestra.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Roddenberry had a vision of an 'enlightened' humanity, and as a strict matter of keeping up appearances, it's a lot easier to sell people on a post-scarcity technologically affluent culture that listens to Chopin over Chuck Berry. It's a bit of an oversight in the long term, because a person's musical tastes aren't necessarily a pointer to their intelligence, but it's such a TV trope to assume intelligence begets classical taste in music that I suspect that has more to do with it than anything. It's a lot easier to sell the idea that music which has already withstood the test of time (Bizet and Berlioz were 19th century composers, both of which are name-dropped during *First Contact*) has "made it into space" with the rest of us than, like, Dion DiMucci. In fact, there's a [brief quote attributed to the creators of Star Trek](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FutureMusic) who state that it is "more believeable" that classical music continues forward whereas contemporary or popular music ebbs, flows, and eventually fades away.

More of an observation on my part -- I'm going out on a limb here, but I would hazard a guess that a utopian society is a lot less likely to identify with some of the darker tones of popular music from the last 70 years.

It's not as if people [stop breaking up with each other](http://youtu.be/sO_9ay6rJCo?t=2m56s) or anything. But there are also certain socio-economic circumstances which are more easily expressed in the context of blues-inspired rock music than in a society where no one gets sick or loses their home because they got fired.

> "Woke up this morning feeling exemplary *--dun daaaa dun da dunt--*
>
> My car started right away because everything works perfectly *--dun
>   daaaa dun da dunt--*
>
> Still happily married because the hardship of
>   financial difficulty never drove me or my spouse to seek the comfort
>   of another person's embrace *--dun daaa dun da dunt--*...."

There are a handful of indicators towards such an attitude. The [small talk between Jellico and Riker concerning the presence of a trombone in his quarters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePTiYrARlsc) is a little telling of the remnants of 'snooty' early TNG's vision of humans -- we're all high-concept highfalutin brainiacs that immerse ourselves in the high points of art, philosophy, and use phrases like "Is it not the height of hubris..." (Really though, the reaction and body language Jellico employs when Riker says he's a jazz musician -- 'ohhhh *....jazz*..... okaaay.')

Comment: I like, especially the "snooty high-concept highfalutin brainiacs" part. So rock is too lowbrow for the future, more refined taste buds?

Comment: Good points all around. To extend your points then we could have expected to see a resurgence of the music we're used to today during DSN and VOY, but we didn't. (DSN with the war and thousands of people dying, planets being seiged, etc. And a crew stuck in the back end of the galaxy and nearly destroyed every week).

Answer (score 23):

You're correct that classical music does seem to be over represented, especially on the Next Generation. However, there are other times when characters do show a taste in alternative genres.

As you already pointed out Riker likes jazz, and is seen on more than one occasion to be performing with others on the Enterprise.

Worf is a fan of Klingon opera and the Doctor on Voyager is also an opera aficionado, albeit that of a more Human origin.

Multiple members of the command staff on Deep Space Nine are seen to enjoy Vic Fontaine's singing, which Memory-Alpha describes as "vocal-jazz and cabaret".

However, there are only two examples of any sort of rock and roll that I am aware of in the 24th century, both in Voyager. The first is in the episode [Vis à Vis](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Vis_%C3%A0_Vis_(episode)) during the opening, when Tom is working on a car in the holodeck there is "surf rock" music playing on a radio. The second is in the episode [Homestead](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Homestead_(episode)), again during the opening there is rock music playing on a jukebox in the mess hall during the First Contact Day celebration.

Comment: Given Tom's fanaticism for the later 20th century, 2 rocks songs in all of *Voyager* is a surprisingly little. Oh, but Harry Kim can play some jazz on his clarinet.

Comment: In *Homestead*, wasn't the reason for playing that music that it was a favorite of then very-late Zefram Cochrane?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes it was, but no one was crying out for it to be turned off.

Comment: @Xantec Good point. Of course, I don't think anyone complained that it *was* turned off for a discussion involving three people, either.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling True. So we can likely gather that rock and roll is a historical curiosity in the 24th century. Mirthfully tolerated by people of the day as a fun jaunt back in time, but not something they'd listen to on a regular basis.

Comment: @Xantec Elevator music rather that Molly Hatchet? I now understand why they drink synthehol rather than the real thing.

Answer (score 13):

There is one other out-of-universe reason for this that's worth noting:

**Money**.

The entire recorded history of Rock and Roll is under copyright. Any use of a song which the audience would recognize could cost a potentially significant amount of money. Better to just restrict any 'historic' music that characters are fond of to works in the public domain that can be used cheaply and without the headache and hassle of all those licenses and publishing rights. If you need evidence of *just how much* of a headache all of that can be... look no further than what happened to [WKRP in Cincinnati.](http://zvbxrpl.blogspot.com/2007/03/wkrp-dvd-not-ok.html)

Comment: +1 Indeed, old Scooby-Doo cartoons are great for this. Lots of the background music is *very much like* certain popular songs.

Answer (score 13):

No one likes to remember it, but it happened.

[image: Star Trek Hippies (from a recent facebook post)]

The third season had some issues.

Answer (score 1):

C'mon, be reasonable - it's pop music from 300-400 years in the past! Diegetically speaking production issues aside), how many people do you know who listen to 16th century popular music? Anyone? Renaissance faires excluded.

Comment: Sure but Jazz is the same age and Classical even older.  Star Fleet is full of the future equivalent of Ren Faire folk with their knowledge and references to ancient stuff.

Comment: Classical music kinda ... is already popular music from 300-400 years ago. High-class popular music, to be sure, but we don't have a true equivalent genre of new, modern music that caters exclusively to the rich and powerful. (For example, the Medici family [commissioned some of the most popular music of the 1500's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermedio).) Not that hard to imagine the biggest names in popular music from today surviving 300-400 years on their own right.

Answer (score -1):

Most classical is copyrighted too. I'd guess that Gene was portraying a technology that would make playing rock music impossible, I mean the power systems they used, operating an electric guitar and an electric bass would be impossible. I mean it took B'elenna 6 months to figure out how to get a TV set to work on a live fed plasma power system. They portrayed what would be feasible with their power systems.

Comment: Most classical music is old enough to be in the public domain. It's only the recordings of performances that are copyrighted.