# Does Rock Music Still Exist in the 24th Century?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, rock-music

Whenever we hear a crew member playing music aboard one of the Starfleet ships in the series (Enterprise or Voyager) it's usually something classical, jazz, or something else easy listening.

Does rock music or metal not exist anymore in the 24th century? Would this music be considered too 'violent' for human culture of the future? It would likely be something better suited to a Klingon's musical tastes.

We never hear a crew member mention "I'm listening to a band from the 20th century who called themselves The Rolling Stones" for example.

Comment: [Xantec's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/65488/20774) calls out at least two occasions when contemporary(ish) Rock Music is played on Voyager.

Comment: @Valorum no one mentioned zefram Cochran playing rock and Riker calling it classical!!

Comment: @Himarm - Not 24th Century, that's why.

Comment: @Valorum ah but they Know what it is, and its been retagged to classical!

Comment: Short answer: No. Rock music no longer exists. Why? Kirk screwed up the timeline.